# How can I make my html code and php contact form file work?

Tags: php, html

I am having problems getting my contact.php form to work. Before I was not getting the message to my email at all, now, the email does get sent, this is all it shows:

```
From:  
E-mail:  
Message:
```

This is my html form:

```
<form role="form" class="form-alt" action="contact.php" method="post">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="name" class="sr-only">name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Name (Required)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="email" class="sr-only">Email</label>
                <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email (Required)">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="subject" class="sr-only">Subject</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control" id="subject" placeholder="Subject">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="message" class="sr-only">message</label>
                <textarea id="message" class="form-control" cols="30" rows="7" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Enviar</button>
        </form>

        </div>
```

And this is the PHP Contact file:

```
<?php
$field_name = $_POST['cf_name'];
$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];
$field_message = $_POST['cf_message'];

$mail_to = 'mail@example.com';
$subject = 'Message from a site visitor '.$field_name;

$body_message = 'From: '.$field_name."\n";
$body_message .= 'E-mail: '.$field_email."\n";
$body_message .= 'Message: '.$field_message;

$headers = 'From: '.$field_email."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Reply-To: '.$field_email."\r\n";

$mail_status = mail($mail_to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

if ($mail_status) { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Thank you for the message. We will contact you shortly.');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        alert('Message failed. Please, send an email to gordon@template-help.com');
        window.location = 'contact_page.html';
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to give each of your form elements a name attribute. For example:

```
<input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email (Required)">
```

should be:

```
<input type="email" name="cf_email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Email (Required)">
```

Your code, e.g. `$field_email = $_POST['cf_email'];` is looking for an input element with the name `cf_email`. Without it you'd get a blank value.

Comment: +1 Just to be clear, POSTed variables use the "name" attribute rather than id. There is nothing wrong with using an id in HTML as it does seem more generally useful and consistent, but a person must give name attributes to form fields they want to be sent on submission in this way.